# Suspend a child process spawned by java

Tags: java, spawn, suspend, child-process

I have a java program which uses `Runtime.exec()` to spawn a child process, but I need to be able to programatically suspend it and then start it running again from where it left off.  The Java `Process` object doesn't seem to provide any way to do that.  Does anyone know how I might accomplish this?

Thank you

Comment: Assuming there is a way to do this, it seems dangerous. How do you know at what execution point your child process will be stopped?  Is the child process a java app?  Maybe use some sort of IPC (interprocess communications) mechanism instead?

Comment: The child process is a call to clasp: http://www.cs.uni-potsdam.de/clasp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under UNIX you can Runtime.exec + kill -STOP and -CONT to suspend and resume a process, without using JNI.

Comment: Although you are absolutely correct but  let me just say Java is made to be environment independent. Using OS specific commands will take away java's main feature.

Comment: That's a great idea.  Thanks.  I realize Java is all about compatibility, but I use it because I like type-safety, good supporting tools (like eclipse), and the well-documented comprehensive standard library

Comment: Oh wait, how do I find out the process number?

Comment: @AdelBoutros You would have to find command line utilities which suspended and resumed a process. Perhaps one of the sysinternals.

Answer (score 2):

Java is not a low level language. Thus, some interactions with the Operating System are not supported.

The only solution is for you to create your code using a language which can really work with the OS such C/C++ and call it from java using JNI.