# Do spawned child processes count as user time?

Tags: java, time, overhead, kill-process, child-process

I have a Java process that starts a bunch of child processes and interleaves them by executing to "kill -STOP" and "kill -CONT" (following the suggestion given in [Suspend a child process spawned by java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248484/suspend-a-child-process-spawned-by-java))

Now I want to time the process. I run "time java [...]"

and the resulting "user" time is about half the "real" time ("sys" time is negligible).

Whether child processes count as "user" time or not, this doesn't make sense because (unless my code is using significantly more CPU than I thought) most of the time spent by my java code is spent (or rather should be spent) waiting (via a `wait(10000)` loop which wakes up every ten seconds to kill -STOP one process and kill -CONT another until one of them successfully returns).

Is there a lot of overhead to calling `kill` (ie is ten seconds too short an interval)? Do child processes count towards user time? If so, what else could account for the discrepancy?